# Perldoc using wrong encoding for copyright symbol

Tags: perl, utf-8, perl-pod

I've noticed that [Pod::Usage](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html) `pod2man`, and even `pod2markdown` are doing the wrong encoding in their output for certain characters. These programs are encoding the copyright symbol as a single byte `0xA9` which is its Unicode Code Point as well as its iso-8859-1 and cp1252 encodings, not its utf-8 encoding  which should be the multibyte `0xCA:0xA9`.

The issue has to do with `Pod::Escapes` which I've updated to version 1.07 (the latest version) and `utf8::unicode_to_native` (which I can't find).

Looking at `Pod::Escape`,  the `%Name2character_number` hash sets the key `copy` to the unicode character point `0xA9` (`169`) which is correct.

However, the `%Name2character` hash is getting the wrong representation from the `utf8::unicode_to_native` subroutine. In fact, all of the Unicode character codes `0x80` to `0xFF` are being set as their single byte representation and not as the utf-8 encoding. All characters above `0xFF` are being set correctly.

Is there a way to fix this issue? I am running Perl 5.18.2 on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) which is natively utf-8.

Comment: "Native" refers to ASCII vs EBCDIC. `unicode_to_native` is not suppose to encode, so it's returning what it should. The problem is elsewhere

Comment: If you are sure this is incorrect behavior, then I highly recommend you report it to the Perl community.  You would be doing EVERYONE a great favor by getting this fixed in the next version of Perl :)

Comment: I was hoping it was something I was _doing wrong_. For example, I have my environment set incorrectly, or the issue is with my `groff` or `troff` on my Mac and this isn't a Perl issue, but a Mac issue. Playing around with this more, I realize this happens with all the characters encoded from `0x80` to `0xFF`, but works fine for anything encoded above `0xFF`.